# How to display the addition of 2 dice rolled

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming in pygame and for my coursework, I'm recreating a game of monopoly.

I have the dice rolling which is fine but I can't seem to find a way to display the numbers that show up on the dice. I just keep getting the initial value of 0. I want to find a way to be able to say, for example, "You rolled an 8"

Also, I'm not sure how to make it so the player cannot roll again until they have moved.

Any help would be much appreciated,

this is just a snippet of the code

```
diceValue1 = 0
diceValue2 = 0
combinedValue = 0
# Dice Roll
class Dice1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()

        #  All dice's images (Dice 1)
        image1 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/1.png')
        image1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image1,(60,60))

        image2 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/2.png')
        image2 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image2,(60,60))

        image3 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/3.png')
        image3 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image3,(60,60))

        image4 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/4.png')
        image4 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image4,(60,60))

        image5 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/5.png')
        image5 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image5,(60,60))

        image6 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/6.png')
        image6 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image6,(60,60))

        self.images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
        self.imageindex = 0

        #  Other arguments
        self.num = num
        self.image = self.images[self.imageindex]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (750, 140))

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            #  Roll the dice
            self.imageindex = random.randint(0, 5)
            if self.imageindex == 1:
                diceValue1 = 1
            elif self.imageindex == 2:
                diceValue1 = 2
            elif self.imageindex == 3:
                diceValue1 = 3
            elif self.imageindex == 4:
                diceValue1 = 4
            elif self.imageindex == 5:
                diceValue1 = 5
            elif self.imageindex == 6:
                diceValue1 = 6
            self.image = self.images[self.imageindex]

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        return diceValue1

class Dice2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()

        #  All dice's images (Dice 1)
        image1 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/1.png')
        image1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image1,(60,60))

        image2 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/2.png')
        image2 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image2,(60,60))

        image3 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/3.png')
        image3 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image3,(60,60))

        image4 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/4.png')
        image4 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image4,(60,60))

        image5 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/5.png')
        image5 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image5,(60,60))

        image6 = pygame.image.load('Images/Dice/6.png')
        image6 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image6,(60,60))

        self.images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
        self.imageindex = 0

        #  Other arguments
        self.num = num
        self.image = self.images[self.imageindex]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (850, 140))

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            #  Roll the dice
            self.imageindex = random.randint(0, 5)
            if self.imageindex == 1:
                diceValue2 = 1
            elif self.imageindex == 2:
                diceValue2 = 2
            elif self.imageindex == 3:
                diceValue2 = 3
            elif self.imageindex == 4:
                diceValue2 = 4
            elif self.imageindex == 5:
                diceValue2 = 5
            elif self.imageindex == 6:
                diceValue2 = 6
            self.image = self.images[self.imageindex]

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        return diceValue2



#  Prompt
prompt_surf = title_font.render('Press SPACE!', False, (25, 25, 25))
prompt_rect = prompt_surf.get_rect(midtop = (800, 100))


#  Create the dice
dice_group1 = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
dice_group1.add(Dice1(1))

dice_group2 = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
dice_group2.add(Dice2(1))

combinedValue = diceValue1 + diceValue2
combinedValue_surf = title_font.render("You rolled " + str(combinedValue), False, (25,25,25))
combinedValue_rect = combinedValue_surf.get_rect(midtop = (800,210))
```

I cant find many youtube videos focusing on this, most of them are just explaining how to get the dice rolling in the first place but not updating a running total

Comment: `Dice1` and `Dice2` are almost identical. Why do you need two separate classes? The only difference is the image position, you should make that a parameter to the `__init__()` method of the class.

Comment: `diceValue1` and `diceValue2` are local variables in their respective functions. You need to make them instance variables, e.g. `self.diceValue`